# How to transfer an int via DatagramSocket

Tags: java, udp, datagram

I wanna do a simple application to transfer integers via DatagramSockets, but I didn't want to do workarounds like using Strings and casting them to int, I'd rather know if there is a adhoc way to pass integers via DatagramSocket.

```
//sender side
public void Send() throws Exception {
    DatagramSocket socket = new DatagramSocket(3000);
    int x = 5;
    DatagramPacket sendPacket = ...
    socket.send(sendPacket);
}

//reeceiver side
public void Receive() throws Exception {
    DatagramSocket socket = new DatagramSocket(2000);
    DatagramPacket receivePacket = ...
    socket.receive(receivePacket);  
    int x = (int) receivePacket;
}
```

Part of this code is just to demonstrate what I want. I'd like to know how to write an int in the sender side and how to read this int in the receiver side.

Comment: what have you tried so far?

Comment: Please provide your code.

Comment: This is the code I'm using, although I wrote an illustrative part to show that I'm searching a straightforward way to read/write ints via DatagramSockets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a [`ByteBuffer`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/ByteBuffer.html).

```
SocketAddress address = ...
int value = ...

byte[] buf = ByteBuffer.allocate(Integer.BYTES).putInt(value).array();
socket.send(new DatagramPacket(buf, buf.length, address));
```

Comment: This looks like some kind of magic. How can I read this int from the byte array that the receiver gets?

Comment: @Daniel Read the javadoc of `ByteBuffer` (link already provided in answer), and you'll find the methods needed to do it in reverse. It's amazing what gems you'll find when you do a little bit of research.